# "I'll go wherever you **will** go" & "**Wherever** you go, I'll be with you"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-usage

Sentence 1: I'll go wherever you **will** go.

Sentence 2: **Wherever** you go, I'll be with you.

Do the above sentences sound natural?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

These kinds of sentences (with 'if', 'when', 'where', 'whenever', 'wherever' etc) usually have **one** *will* or *'ll* - and that is attached to the half of the sentence without the 'if', 'when', 'wherever' - even though the idea of 'will' is there in the other half of the sentence.

Your sentence 1 contains *'ll* in the first half of the sentence and *will* in the second. Yes, you *will* go to many places, but standard English says 'I'll go wherever *you go*'.

Your sentence 2 is standard English - there is one *'ll* (in the second half of the sentence).

Many ESL students say and write things like 'I'll go wherever you will go', and it *is* clear and easily understandable (I sometimes refer to it as a 'good mistake'). Some native English speakers or writers may also say or write it, but it is much rarer than 'wherever you go' (Google Ngram [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wherever%20you%20will%20go%2Cwherever%20you%20go&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwherever%20you%20will%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwherever%20you%20go%3B%2Cc0)).